# Move table to the left / change left margin of particular frame

Tags: beamer, floats, margins

I'm trying to move my table to the left with no success. I found `\hspace`, but it seem to not work. Here is my slide:

```
\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Test slide}
\vspace{-0.4cm}
\hspace{-1cm}
\begin{tabular}[t]{p{5.4cm}p{5.8cm}}
\vspace{0pt} \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{eleanor_scriven_2429776k.jpg} &
\begin{enumerate}[<+->]
\item This is test text This is test text 
\item This is test text This is test text 
\item This is test text This is test text 
\item This is test text This is test text 
\item This is test text This is test text 
\end{enumerate}
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can box it and then move it; for example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test slide}

\hspace*{-8pt}\makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
\begin{tabular}[t]{p{5.4cm}p{5.8cm}}
\vspace{0pt} \includegraphics[width=5.3cm]{ctanlion} &
\begin{enumerate}[<+->]
\item This is test text This is test text 
\item This is test text This is test text 
\item This is test text This is test text 
\item This is test text This is test text 
\item This is test text This is test text 
\end{enumerate}
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, instead of shifting the table to the left, I'd suggest you to consider some alternatives: reducing the intercolumn space, reducing the font, or resizing the table; this last approach can be done using `\resizebox`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test slide}

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}[t]{p{5.4cm}p{5.8cm}}
\vspace{0pt} \includegraphics[width=5.3cm]{ctanlion} &
\begin{enumerate}[<+->]
\item This is test text This is test text 
\item This is test text This is test text 
\item This is test text This is test text 
\item This is test text This is test text 
\item This is test text This is test text 
\end{enumerate}
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

CTAN lion drawing by Duane Bibby.