# beamer shift gb4e gloss left

Tags: beamer, numbering, positioning, gb4e

I have a `gb4e` gloss that does not fit my beamer slide horizontally. I use an empty, yet space consuming identifier with `\exi{}`, therefore I would like to shift the gloss to the left.

I have tried various variants of `\hspace{-1cm}`, notably [Move table to the left / change left margin of particular frame](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102815/move-table-to-the-left-change-left-margin-of-particular-frame), but I get either no change in the output or an error stating `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item`. How can I shift the gloss, or otherwise fit it on one line?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
%\hspace*{-1cm}\makebox[\linewidth][c]{% triggers 'perhaps missing \item'
\hspace{-1cm}
\begin{exe}
\exi{}
\gll Unser Zeitalter ist das eigentliche Zeitalter der Kritik,\\
Our age is the actual age of criticism,\\
\end{exe}%
%}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/347647/36296

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{changepage}
\noautomath
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
normal text

\begin{adjustwidth}{-3.3em}{1em}
\begin{exe}
\exi{}
\gll Unser Zeitalter ist das eigentliche Zeitalter der Kritik,\\
Our age is the actual age of criticism,\\
\end{exe}%
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]