# How to change indentation/margins of quote environment in Beamer

Tags: beamer, indentation, quoting

I need to put a quote between `itemize` items in a `beamer` `frame`. If I stop and restart `itemize` around the quote the result's not indented at all:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\setbeamerfont{quote}{shape=\upshape,family=\rmfamily}

\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame}

\begin{itemize}

\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 

\end{itemize}

\begin{quote}Sed vitae purus facilisis, blandit odio eget, tincidunt nisi. Aliquam pulvinar, ipsum ac aliquet facilisis, neque quam tincidunt lacus, at eleifend ante lorem quis neque. Suspendisse potenti. \end{quote}

\begin{itemize}

\item Nulla vel bibendum ligula. Sed imperdiet felis lacus, a vulputate urna egestas at.

\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

But if I don't restart the quote is indented too much:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS} \usefonttheme{serif} \setbeamerfont{quote}{shape=\upshape,family=\rmfamily}

\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame}

\begin{itemize}

\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \smallskip{}

\begin{quote}Sed vitae purus facilisis, blandit odio eget, tincidunt nisi. Aliquam pulvinar, ipsum ac aliquet facilisis, neque quam tincidunt lacus, at eleifend ante lorem quis neque. Suspendisse potenti. \end{quote}

\item Nulla vel bibendum ligula. Sed imperdiet felis lacus, a vulputate urna egestas at.

\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I'm guessing that I will have to redefine the `quote` environment from `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty`.  How would that go?  It's probably in the `beamer` user guide, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`changepage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage)'s `adjustwidth` environment to adjust the margins around your quote:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94159/5764

\usepackage{changepage}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\setbeamerfont{quote}{shape=\upshape,family=\rmfamily}

\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame}

\begin{itemize}

\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \smallskip{}

\begin{quote}
Sed vitae purus facilisis, blandit odio eget, tincidunt nisi. Aliquam pulvinar, ipsum ac aliquet facilisis, neque quam tincidunt lacus, at eleifend ante lorem quis neque. Suspendisse potenti.
\end{quote}

\begin{adjustwidth}{1em}{1em}
Sed vitae purus facilisis, blandit odio eget, tincidunt nisi. Aliquam pulvinar, ipsum ac aliquet facilisis, neque quam tincidunt lacus, at eleifend ante lorem quis neque. Suspendisse potenti.
\end{adjustwidth}

\item Nulla vel bibendum ligula. Sed imperdiet felis lacus, a vulputate urna egestas at.

\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You can perform a complete replacement of the `quote` environment with that of an `adjustwidth` one using (say)

```
\renewenvironment{quote}[1][1em]
  {\begin{adjustwidth}{#1}{#1}}
  {\end{adjustwidth}}
```

The above redefinition provides

```
\begin{quote}[<margin>]
  <quote>
\end{quote}
```

with an optional `<margin>` argument that are used for the left and right margin adjustments.

Comment: This works great, but has to be done for every occurrence of quote. Is it possible to make the change for all quotes in a Beamer file?

Comment: @ss1789: See the updated answer.